# Create bam from separate sam and header

Tags: samtools, bash

If I have multiple SAM files without header, and a header saved in a separate file, how do I convert that to a BAM file?

One solution is to create intermediate files:

```
for samfile in *.sam
do
  cat my_header > tmp.sam
  cat $samfile >> tmp.sam
  samtools view -b tmp.sam > $samfile.bam
done
```

But that seems inelegant and I feel like I'm missing the better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use GNU parallel. I've not tested this with real files but try it out, ensure the `{}` is passed to the process substitution:

```
mkdir with_header
parallel samtools view -b <(cat my_header {}) -o with_header/{} ::: *.bam
```

The command could be better - out file name could be done better but you get the concept.